# Exclude windows folder in search file

Tags: c++

I have a little code that search all drives to find all `txt` extension, But my problem is, I want exclude *Windows* folder in system drive, I tested many situation but it doesn't work, My code is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

void FindFilesRecursively(LPCTSTR lpFolder, LPCTSTR lpFilePattern)
{
    TCHAR szFullPattern[MAX_PATH];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFindFile;
    // first we are going to process any subdirectories
    PathCombine(szFullPattern, lpFolder,_T("*"));
    hFindFile = FindFirstFile(szFullPattern, &FindFileData);
    if(hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
            if (_tcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, _T("."))  != 0 &&
      _tcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, _T("..")) != 0)
  {
                // found a subdirectory; recurse into it
                PathCombine(szFullPattern, lpFolder, FindFileData.cFileName);
                FindFilesRecursively(szFullPattern, lpFilePattern);
                //_tprintf_s(_T("%s\n"), lpFolder);
                }
            }
        } while(FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindFileData));
        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
    // now we are going to look for the matching files
    PathCombine(szFullPattern, lpFolder, lpFilePattern);
    hFindFile = FindFirstFile(szFullPattern, &FindFileData);
    if(hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if(!(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            {
                // found a file; do something with it
                PathCombine(szFullPattern, lpFolder, FindFileData.cFileName);
                _tprintf_s(_T("%s\n"), szFullPattern);
            }
        } while(FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindFileData));
        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
}

DWORD mydrives = 100;// buffer length
char lpBuffer[100];// buffer for drive string storage
int main()
{
    DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
    char szLogicalDrives[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    DWORD dwResult = GetLogicalDriveStrings(dwSize,szLogicalDrives);

    if (dwResult > 0 && dwResult <= MAX_PATH)
    {
        char* szSingleDrive = szLogicalDrives;
        while(*szSingleDrive)
        {

            // get the next drive
            FindFilesRecursively(_T(szSingleDrive), _T("*.txt"));
            szSingleDrive += strlen(szSingleDrive) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested `_tcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, _T("C:\windows")) != 0` and etc but it did not work, Also I want to know How can I use `getenv ("SystemDrive");` in my code to detect systemdrive and use it instead of `C:\`, Sorry in advance

Comment: Beware: NTFS file system is not case sensitive, but file names **have** case so you should use `_tcsicmp` to make a case-insensitive comparison of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FindFileData.cFileName` parameter is relative to the search directory, `lpFolder` in this case. To get the full filename, you need to concatenate the `cFileName` with `lpFolder` -- this full filename you can compare to the Windows directory. You've already done this in `szFullPattern` inside the find loop, it seems, so you can use that to compare to the Windows directory.

As mentioned in the other answer, use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) (Vista and higher) or `SHGetFolderPath` to get the directory and do a case-insensitive comparison.